# How to distribute a windows application?

Tags: windows, software-distribution

What's the best way to distribute a windows application:

- Which format should i use to distribute the application, an exe-file
  or a zip-file?
- Should i sign the application?

Are there any other points i should take into account?

I'm going to create an installer for the application using innosetup. The application is made using node-webkit.

Answer (score 3):

(I'm not a Windows user, but) MSI package is better than *both* an exe-file and a zip-file. The freedom to choose interactive or unattended [un]installation, and the ability to handle dependencies and upgrades are enough to make it the best option. WiX makes MSI creation easier -- give it a try.

Comment: MSI packages can only install dependencies that are in merge modules; a .exe bootstrapper created using something like Burn can also install other exe and msi packages. It also handles silent installs and upgrades too.

Answer (score 2):

So long as the application deploys - it makes no functional difference the data format you choose to distribute in.

I will speak from a user perspective as opposed to a technical one here; please include a CLEARLY LABELED installer (MSI is the best for this; but if it is .exe, or .bat or whatever, label it as "Installer" or "Click to install" or something similar) and a useful readme, if you do choose to distribute in a .zip.

Comment: More depends on how useful the application is. Maybe .zip looks somewhat old fashioned but a good application for advanced user (say some ssh client) surely could be distributed that way. Some may prefer to have control over installer actions. Too many installers add spam shortcuts, useless extras nobody asked for, trash in the registry and the like.

Comment: Agreed - that's another point for .zip; a lot of more..."advanced" users like to see what is going on and have more direct control over files and the installer.

Comment: the installer will just place a simple exe and some required dll's in the program files directory ... so much control isn't required i believe ... you should be able to choose where to place it and if you want a desktop icon or not ... so an msi might be overkill i think. Also an exe is very easy to make :) the problem i see with exe files is that if you download them from the internet they might be blocked? that's why i was thinking of adding the exe in a zip file ...

Comment: Good point. At very least, an .exe might post some kind of warning to the user that the software may be harmful - that may be enough to ward off inexperienced or particularly cautious customers. Again, this question is largely subjective - but I am definitely leaning towards a .zip what with the points made in these comments.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what the exe entails. If it's just a simple .NET executable and it's self contained, all you need is the exe in a zip (pending it's < .NET 2.0 which is included). Each newer succeeding version of Windows has .NET runtimes built into the OS incrementing all the way up to 4.5 or 5.0?

So if you have the latest Windows, and it has the .NET 4.5 libraries on it, all you need is essentially the executable. However if it is an older OS, you may need to bundle or link the runtimes needed. Some apps need third party components installed and other DLL's. In which case your best bet would be to use a third party tool like Install Shield or Wise, or Orca, where you can customize the install and install third party components like SQL Server Personal, Oracle Personal or mySQL Database or Crystal report components.

Also if NTFS permissions and network permissions are required or registry values are required you'll need to script it with Wise, InstallShield, etc, and require elevated permissions. Microsoft also has some built in Deploy Once(?) tools that allows this to be done via the web, or network path or executable.

It all depends on the complexity of your exe, how much it effects your system etc. I've seen apps that require even firewall exceptions, etc. If you are in a corporate environment and have a domain you can deploy using SCCM/SMS or UniCenter. Like I said it all depends on complexity, and scope.

If it's a simple .NET 2.0 app, then all you need is the exe in a zip. The best way would be to copy the exe to a few different systems and test it.

MSI's are inherently able to execute from shell or run/explorer. Also you are allowed to compile your install into a self contained executable.

Bottom line, it all depends on your app :)